# Having trouble display Bitmap image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I wanted to display a bitmap image from my drawable resources folder. When I click on an object, I want to be able to display the image that corresponds with that view. Here are my code and XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pokemon_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor = "@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop = "6dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pokemon_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pokemon_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cd" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pokemon_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So the problem is that the image I create through the use of Bitmap doesn't show up. I have it iterating through my Drawable Resources folder, where the name of the png file is supposed to equal the name of the object I click. In my log statements, it seems to pass the if check, but it doesn't form my image when I try to run it.

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pokemon_image);

    Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();

    int resourceID = -1;

    for(int count=0; count < fields.length; count++)
    {
        Log.i("Drawable Asset: ", fields[count].getName());
        Log.d("tag", "Resource ID is " + resourceID);

        Log.d("check", "Resource ID and name are the same: " + 
                fields[count].getName().equals(name.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));

        if(fields[count].getName().equals(name.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)));
        {
                try {
                    resourceID=fields[count].getInt(fields[count]);
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceID);

                    image.setImageBitmap(bm);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oringinal answer deleted, not applicable.

New answer:

Instead of reflection, use

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName()));
```

where name is the name of the file in order to get the drawable to display.

Or use assets instead of resources, which is a better fit when you're going to be looking up by name.

Comment: I figured I didn't need that because I was going to be setting it to something else via the Bitmap.

Comment: You don't if you are setting it in code, but are you sure you're getting to the line which is?  I'm not sure what name is in the above code (we don't see its value), but its extremely unusual and probably wrong to be doing reflection like that.  I can't even figure out what you're trying to do.  But if you think you're iterating over all drawables in your resources-  you definitely aren't.  You're iterating over all the internal variables in the Drawable class.

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit fearful of putting all the code since this is my own app I'm creating, which is why I put only that method. The name is passing through fine though, and when I looked at the Log.d statements it was iterating through the drawables resource. I wanted to create an array of all the drawable resources, and then check if it equals the name (which is why I ran that Log.d statement where it checks where it equals, which turned out true for the one I was intending). So I know it went inside that if statement, but it didn't really do anything inside that try block.

Comment: Then your code is completely wrong.  Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();  will not get you a list of all drawable resources.  It will give you a list of all the variables in the drawable class.

Comment: The reason I did that was because I did the exact thing when I needed to parse JSON files, and it worked. I'm guessing it's going to be completely different for images?

Comment: That can make sense for creating an object based on JSON, because you want to manipulate iniividual variables in a single object.  It makes no sense here-  you want to get an array of all objects in a given location.  That has nothing to do with reflection at all.

Comment: Well, first I'm going to suggest you don't do it this way-  put the images in assets instead of resources.  That's made to be a searchable filesystem, resources isn't.  If you really want to use resources for some reason, use  Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(getResources()
                  .getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", getPackageName()));  This will give you the drawable for the requested name